# Subclasses of UISearchBar and UISearchController breaks VoiceOver

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller, voiceover, uiaccessibility

In my app I have a `UIViewController` that lets users search in a server database. (It's not filtering an existing list.) Results are displayed in a `UITableView`, which is the `searchResultsController` of the custom `UISearchController`.

We need a different behaviour of the 'Cancel' button so we created subclasses of UISearchController and UISearchBar.

My issue is: VoiceOver doesn't see the `UITableView` that display results. Instead of selecting the header, then the first row and so on, it selects the whole area and reads something about closing the view. (There's no 'Close' button). It seems like the `UITableView` showing the results is hidden. Here's the view hierarchy when the `searchResultsController` is presented.

[image: View hierarchy when the <code>searchResultsController</code> is presented]

If I initiate the `searchController` with the default class, I get the correct behaviour (for VoiceOver, not for the 'Cancel' button).

The documentation doesn't say anything specific about subclassing.

**Any hint?**

Here's the code when we initialize them:

```
    //Showing results
self.resultsTableController = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
self.resultsTableController.tableView.delegate = self;
self.resultsTableController.tableView.dataSource = self;
self.resultsTableController.tableView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeOnDrag;

// Configuring searchController
self.searchController = [[RedactedNameSearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:self.resultsTableController];
// When initialized with UISearchController, it works:
//  self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:self.resultsTableController];
[self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;
self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
self.searchController.delegate = self;
self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self ;
```

`UISearchController` subclass code:

```
@interface MySearchController () {
    UISearchBar *searchBar;
}
@end

@implementation MySearchController

- (UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    if (searchBar == nil) {
        searchBar = [[MySearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        searchBar.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeAllCharacters;
        searchBar.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    }
    return searchBar;
}
@end
```

`UISearchBar is implemented like so:

```
@implementation MySearchBar

-(void)setShowsCancelButton:(BOOL)showsCancelButton {
}

-(void)setShowsCancelButton:(BOOL)showsCancelButton animated:(BOOL)animated {
}

@end
```

Comment: In your `MySearchBar` implementation, what if you call `[super setShowsCancelButton:NO];` (or whichever you wanted)? I just wonder if some implementation detail is messed up because you're not calling super.

Comment: Great suggestion! However, it doesn't have any effect.

Comment: i have the exact same problem, did you find any solution?

Comment: Sorry I don't remember and I don't work on that project anymore.